# Laravel configuration file structure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

We are using same code base for multiple sites. And there are will be config files which are both site specific and common settings. We want to merge the common settings with site specific settings.

Our config folder structure is -

app/config -

- ssc/
- brg/
- app.php
- common.php

and so on. `ssc` and `brg` will hold site specific configs for `ssc` & `brg` sites respectively.

And for this we have to do -

```
    config('common');
    config('brg.settings');
```

But in our code base we have not used the sub-folder mechanism. When we will be implementing the sub-folder system then we have to make changes to the code base to implement the site specific folder which I want to avoid.

Is there any way to implement the sub-folder system and dont have to changes the code base?

Comment: `config()->all()` would return all of the configuration items for the application.

Comment: Yes. But I want to avoid to use the folder name as the code is develop. I want something like merging configs inside the folder to outer elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In a multi-tenant environment**

You can merge the settings into the common config inside a middleware or at the point you know which site you are in:

```
config('common');
config('brg.settings'); // inside each have the same keys
config('ssc.settings'); // inside each have the same keys
```

So lets say you want `common.settings` where `settings` comes from either `brg.settings` or `scc.settings` you can try something like the following:

```
config([
    'common' => array_merge(
        config('brg'), 
        config('common')
    )
]);
```

If you want to amend it so that `brg.settings` become keys inside common try the following:

```
config([
    'common' => array_merge(
        config('brg.settings'), 
        config('common')
    )
]);
```

**Update - For a shared (copied) folder approach**

Lets say your config folder has:

```
config/common.php
config/brg/settings.php
```

Then you could try and create a symlink from `config/brg/settings.php` to `config/settings.php`

```
$ cd config
$ ln -s brg/settings.php settings.php
```

You might even want to move the `brg/settings.php` out of the config folder into something like `sites/brg/settings/php` to avoid laravel building a composite of all the sites config and just use the symlink in config to what you want.

**Alternatively**

As part of your deployment you can create an artisan command that creates the physical config file you need like, `config/site/settings.php` given the site inside the .env.

I think it is still good to move the site specific config out of the config folder to avoid Laravel needing to parse the unneeded files.

Comment: Yes. But it will include the process for every request.

Comment: Sure, as you mentioned "We are using same code base for multiple sites" I presumed it was a multi-tenant environment? How do you know which site you are in, and does each site share the same physical code base, ie the same location on the drive?

Comment: The code base is same but they will be kept in different folders or on different servers. We have a variable in `.env` file which will store site information.

Comment: Ok, it is clear then, I updated my answer with two other approaches that could help but there is not a nice native Laravel way to ignore the subfolder.

Comment: Well, in that case we would move the site specific setting outside the folder and minimize the configs as much as possible. May be will wait for time if any other solution we could find.